# How to make TCP connection inside a loop in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to write a program that gets IP adress as an input inside a while loop and makes a TCP connection with it.
Here is an example:

```
import socket
s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
while True:
    adress=input('Enter the IP:')
    s1.connect((adress, 8000))
    message=input('Enter the message:')
    s1.send(message.encode())
    s1.close()
```

Server:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.bind(('', 8000))
s.listen(5)
print('ready')
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    recieved_message= c.recv(1024)
    print(recieved_message.decode())
    c.close()
```

It successfully makes the first connection and server recieves the first message but when I try to connect it again by inputting the same IP adress I get this error:

> [WinError 10038] an operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

I removed s1.close() to outside of the while loop to fix thix but this time I got this error:

> [WinError 10056] A connection attempt targeted an already connected socket

I can't find way to solve this. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The first error is from reusing a closed socket, and the second error is from reconnecting to an already connected socket.

Put the `s1 =` line inside the `while` loop in the client to  create a new socket for each connection.

```
import socket

while True:
    s1 = socket.socket()
    address = input('Enter the IP:')
    s1.connect((address, 8000))
    message = input('Enter the message:')
    s1.send(message.encode())
    s1.close()
```